# What is a phrase like "Do I Gift a Present or Present a Gift ?" called?

Tags: phrases

I recently came across a sentence of the form - "Do I Gift a Present or Present a Gift ?" and am wondering whether sentences of this type (where words can be interchanged and still make valid, meaningful sentences) are called something ? And whether there are anymore examples ?

I tried googling with the above line but it yields nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of sentences illustrate ***chiasmus***:

> In rhetoric, *chiasmus*... is the figure of speech in which two or more clauses are related to each other through a reversal of structures in order to make a larger point; that is, the clauses display inverted parallelism.
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus))

This passage mentions only *clauses* which showcase inverted order, but sub-clausal constituents like phrases can also exhibit it. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chiasmus) captures this looser definition:

> A rhetorical or literary figure in which words, grammatical constructions, or concepts are repeated in reverse order.

[**NOTE:** Some people use the word *chiasmus* for any repeated but inverted structure, regardless of whether the same words are used. They use *[antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole)* for the stricter notion which involves repeating the same words.]

Here is an example from T. Kane's *The Oxford Essential Guide to Writing*:

> - If there had never been a *danger* to our *constitution* there would never have been a *constitution* to be in *danger*.

Here are some examples that I constructed resembling yours:

> - Should I *bear* the *punch* or *punch* the *bear*?
> - He *kicked* the *duck* and *ducked* the *kick*.

Generally, if you have two words that are both ambiguous between nouns and transitive verbs, you can construct examples like these.